# Select text between 2 complete span tags using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Take the following:

```
<span class='exclass'>1.</span> Lorem Ipsum <span class="exclass2" title="This is an example">*</span>
```

I am trying to create a regex expression that will select:

```
<span class='exclass'>1.</span>
```

AND

```
<span class="exclass2" title="This is an example">*</span>
```

Regex expressions like `^(<span(.*)<\/span>)$` select all of the text.

What expression will select the two complete tags and ignore the loose text between them? (Lorem Ipsum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex is not good way to find HTML tags**. But this should work for you-

```
<\s*span[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*span>
```

**DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/vbLN9L/6

Comment: [reg​ex parsers for HTML will ins​tantly transport a programmer's consciousness into a world of ceaseless screaming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6624953)

Comment: True. I didn't think of it as 'finding/selecting HTML tags' because one of those span tags was just appended onto a string I had stored in a js var beforehand. Thanks!